# Setting label width for tabs

Tags: html, css

I'm messing with [this](http://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/) code sample from CSS Tricks and am trying to set the three tabs width to be 33% of the containers width, so that the three tabs evenly cover the top of the container. I know that you can set the width of labels with display:block, but the label then starts cutting into the container. How can I adjust the width without damaging the container?

Comment: Can you give an example on how your html is structured?

Comment: Exactly like this: http://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qEwef/

Essentially:

```
.tab {
  float: left;
  width:33%;
  display:block;
  margin-top:-12px;
}
.tab label {
  background: #eee; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-left: -1px; 
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
  display:block;
}
```

The margin-top on the tab will back out the padding/border that exists on the tab label.

Comment: Note the display:block added to the ".tab label", too.

Comment: Also, 33.3% gets you much closer to complete coverage.

Comment: That worked great, thanks! I was trying to use bottom margin at 12px but that wasn't working. I didn't think to use top -12.